# ibmmq with nodejs- Unable to make it work with aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, ibm-mq

I am trying to read data from IBM MQ using ibmmq node module. The lambda function works fine with serverless-offline plugin with the below changes in my local environment.

- Downgrading python version to 2.x
- Installing windows build tools, node-gyp, Windows8.0 SDK, visual studio 2015

But the same lambda when deployed in AWS throws the below error

module initialization error: Error
at Error (native)
at bindings (/var/task/node_modules/ibmmq/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
at Object. (/var/task/node_modules/ibmmq/node_modules/ref/lib/ref.js:5:47)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

I have added windows-build-tools to my dependencies. Any ideas on how to make this work

Comment: I don't think the "connection" is the issue.  `Error (native) at bindings` seems to suggest binary incompatibility with the [lambda runtime environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html), which isn't Windows, but I freely admit that I am speculating.

Comment: Yes it's not a connection issue. I have updated the description. When i tried the setup from a windows machine everything worked fine. But I am not sure how to achieve it in aws lambda

Comment: I'm afraid I can't say authoritatively, but my working assumption is that you need to create an EC2 instance using the image mentioned above, and build the external modules there, before packaging everything up for deployment.  That page states that *"If you are using any native binaries in your code, make sure they are compiled in this environment."*  If this is indeed the issue, you *might* find success building then modules under [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).